# Is there an R function for reading a Date in a date_isoweek format?

Tags: r, as.date

I have data in a specifc format year_isoweek, e.g., 2019_31 for this week. And I want this represented as a date for further processing.

basic `r` and `lubridate`; 
I found some work arounds that have merit, but none of these work with ISO 8601 (%V) which leads to other problems in turn: 
[convert year week string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631363/convert-year-week-string-to-date) 
[Convert week number to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470414/convert-week-number-to-date) 
[Transform year/week to date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549449/transform-year-week-to-date-object)

```
a <- c("2019_7", "2019_3", "2018_18")
as.Date(a, "%Y_%V")
```

Actual output:

```
[1] "2019-07-31" "2019-07-31" "2018-07-31"
```

What I want: 
`"2019-02-11" "2019-01-14" "2018-04-30"` as class `date`

Comment: Maybe `strptime(paste0(a, -1), "%Y_%W-%w")`?

Comment: @Matt  I tried this:  `a <- c("2019-7", "2019-3", "2018-18")`   
`b <- strptime(paste0(a, -1), "%Y-%W-%w")`   
`str(b)`   
`POSIXlt[1:3], format: "2019-02-18" "2019-01-21" "2018-04-30"`   
That is not close enough for my purposes. Dates must be within the corresponding ISO 8601 week. (sry, I do not get Line Breaks to work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution using the package `ISOweek`:

```
library(ISOweek)
library(stringr)
a <- c("2019", "2019", "2018")
b <- str_pad(c("7", "3", "18"), 2, pad = "0")
c <- ISOweek2date(paste0(a,"-W",b, "-",1))
str(c)
```

`Date[1:3], format: "2019-02-11" "2019-01-14" "2018-04-30"`
is exactly as 
`"2019-02-11" "2019-01-14" "2018-04-30"` as class `date` as I wanted!

There is an inconvenience with `ISOweek` because it does not accept single digits or single char strings as week numbers (e.g., "7" is not accepted, only "07" is). Therefore, `stringr` package is needed, too.